# Use awk to replace word in file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with some lines:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I would like to `cat` this file into a `awk` command to produce something like this:

```
letter is a
letter is b
letter is c
letter is d
```

using something like this:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'letter is $1'
```

But it's not printing out as expected:

```
$ cat raw.txt | awk 'this is $1'
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Which one is the question, "Use sed to replace word in file" *or* "Use awk to print out lines from file"?

Comment: It was for awk - apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you wanted sed or awk but this is in awk:

```
$ awk '{print "letter is " $1}' file
letter is a
letter is b
letter is c
letter is d
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you have no `{ action }` block, so your condition evaluates the two empty variables `this` and `is`, concatenating them with the first field `$1`, and checks whether the result is *true* (a non-empty string). It is, so the default action prints each line.

It sounds like you want to do this instead:

```
awk '{ print "letter is", $1 }' raw.txt
```

Although in this case, you might as well just use sed:

```
sed 's/^/letter is /' raw.txt
```

This command matches the start of each line and adds the string.

Note that I'm passing the file as an argument, rather than using `cat` with a pipe.